# Why is WordPress not working properly?

Tags: wordpress

A client of ours has the domain http://moneynotes.co.uk/wp, but unfortunately it just shows the page for a second and then shows a blank screen.

Why is this? What is missing or what is wrong?

Comment: This is a known issue. There's an evil warlock lives in a cave in a far away land, he spends his life disrupting peoples Wordpress installs. He really is a terrible person but there's not much anyone can do about it =/ (TL,DR; stupid questions get stupid answers)

Comment: @sam I don't know if it's a *stupid* question. Certainly a question lacking enough detail to solicit an accurate answer.

Comment: We can't possibly diagnose this without access to the code. It's obviously doing something that's causing a 500 error - maybe to do with that Tweet bar or something.

Comment: WP-Admin doesn't work either (Assuming default address), so whatever is broken is good and proper broken.

Edit: Ah, it does, kinda. I think this is a mod-rewrite issue. Maybe.

Comment: It's sending a "moved permanently" response from the server. Something is redirecting.

Comment: God you guys are trolls. It is not a 500 or 404 or anything, turn off your JS and then load the site.

@OP, you have Javascript stuff redirecting loaded pages. Check your java script.

Comment: @Tim - $ wget http://moneynotes.co.uk/wp
--2011-12-09 09:44:22--  http://moneynotes.co.uk/wp
Resolving moneynotes.co.uk... 176.31.241.200
Connecting to moneynotes.co.uk|176.31.241.200|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://moneynotes.co.uk/wp/ [following]
--2011-12-09 09:44:23--  http://moneynotes.co.uk/wp/
Reusing existing connection to moneynotes.co.uk:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-12-09 09:44:23 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: @Tim: OH LOOK A 301 and a 404!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an issue with .htaccess or Mod Rewrite or something similar. After a few seconds your page is directing to the top level directory. If you stop the page while loading, all of the links do the same. I.e.:

http://moneynotes.co.uk/welcome-to-money-notes/

It's the top level that is giving a 500 error.